# ZwQuerySystemInformation / NtQuerySystemInformation - System Information Class 5

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-vista, sdk

For 32-bit Windows, following declaration of `_SYSTEM_PROCESSES` structure ( System Information Class 5 ) with `ZwQuerySystemInformation` works fine for my purpose to construct process tree.

```
typedef struct _SYSTEM_PROCESSES   
{ // System Information Class 5  

     ULONG           NextEntryDelta;   
     ULONG           ThreadCount;  
     ULONG           Reserved1[6];  
     LARGE_INTEGER   CreateTime;  
     LARGE_INTEGER   UserTime;  
     LARGE_INTEGER   KernelTime;  
     UNICODE_STRING  ProcessName;  
     ULONG           BasePriority;  
     ULONG           ProcessId;  
     ULONG           InheritedFromProcessId;  
     ULONG           HandleCount;  
     ULONG           Reserved2[2];  
} SYSTEM_PROCESSES, * PSYSTEM_PROCESSES;
```

On the other hand, it doesn't function well in 64-bit Windows. If I declare the `ProcessId` as `ULONG64`, then the data for `ProcessId` comes right. Is the datatype defined for above structure is right for Windows-64?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some weird reason, process and thread id's are 64bit in the kernel and 32bit in the documented windows api on x64

If you look at [SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/System%20Information/Structures/SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION.html) @ ntinternals you see that they have declared the PID's as HANDLE (pointer sized)